# Should I be using a compile or link?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a new to angular, and I am still having trouble determining if I should be using a link, compile or even controller in this specific situation.

I want to make a custom directive to handle my inputs (should it be hidden, required, etc)

For example I want.

```
<custom-input name="field1" errormessage="This is an error"></custom-input>


app.directive('customInput', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/app/shared/views/custom-input.html',
    controller: function ($scope) {
      ..then something like 
        checkIfRequired(UseNameAttr);
        addProperMasking();
        setErrorMsg(UseAttr);
    }
  }
});
```

Maybe this is all a bad idea..I just have a lot of fields that can be hidden/required depending on the logged in user.

I was thinking compile, since the logic just needs to be done once when the view is requested.. But after all my reading, I'm still not sure.

Comment: Oops. Yes, confused about all three. I was thinking compile or link when I started..but then starting thinking controller. Never changed the title

Comment: Edited question to reflect

Answer (score 0):

you dont have $scope available in compile, but it is available during link. so it boil downs to : do you have some logic which varies per directive instance or its same?

as per what you said, there would a service, isUserAuth(fieldName) something like this, which can be accessed from compile and does not as such depend on scope/route controller

Comment: The logic would be the same. But the 'name' attr would make the end result differ per instance.

Comment: in case its attr.. you can compile